# Можно ли тащить в драйвер обычные linkedlistы на C или юзать только NTшные?

Tags: c, winapi, драйвер, системное-программирование

Пример ситуации.
Есть код драйвера. Там есть минифильтр с каллбеками, который кладет данные в очередь, и отдельный поток, которые каждые n минут проверяет эту очередь, и если заполнена — то передает ее куда-то далее, и очищает\пересоздает очередь.
В качестве очереди автор выбрал никакой не список, а просто `PWCHAR` фиксированной длины, и это, конечно, тоже решение, но, например, оно почти не поддается масштабированию. Надо бы его заменить списком.

Еще пример. Здесь случай уже несколько иной.
В реестре есть настройка — ключ строкового типа, который содержит список строк через разделитель. Логичнее еще в `DriverEntry` распарсить эту строку на linked list, чем парсить ее каждый раз снова и снова. Опять же нужен список.

Объединяет эти случаи одно — и там, и тут нужен список.

Но стоит ли торопиться сразу осваивать специальные списки NT, такие, как `SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY`?
И что, если между тем списки нужны еще на одной платформе — смежной по применению, но в корне отличающейся технически — такой, как микроконтроллеры? Там уж точно не пригодятся знания NT. То есть, тебе всё равно предстоит смотреть самодельные реализации списков на Си с гитхаба, выбирать какую-то из них и допиливать ее.
Приходится всерьез рассмотреть что-то вроде "кроссплатформенности", вернее — переносимости кода.

В основе переделки — замена malloc/free на ExAllocate***/ExFree***.

Менее очевидные нюансы:

- NT обычно требовательно к быстродействию. Ранее уже упоминались
  каллбеки, так они могут вызываться очень много где и очень много раз
  подряд. Чем быстрее они будут отрабатывать — тем лучше. Но разве
  что-то может быть быстрее, чем твоя собственная реализация
  linkedlist'а, где ты можешь реализовать любые свои хотелки, да и
  априори ничего дорогого там вроде нет?
- Синхронизация в NT более
  сложная. В тех же каллбеках иногда доступны лишь спинлоки и
  InterlockedExchange. Тем не менее, не видится проблем все это
  приспособить к списку — если уж он вообще годен в сложившейся
  ситуации как таковой.

Если тащить эти linkedlist'ы в драйвер все-таки решительно нельзя — то я готов с этим согласиться. Но ответ нужен аргументированный, чтобы знать почему, и уметь кому-нибудь объяснить.

**UPD**: Пока решил для себя так: interlocked-списки лучше взять NT-шные (прежде всего это будут sequenced singly linked lists в качестве односвязных, но, *возможно*, еще и doubly linked lists с interlocked-функциями в качестве двусвязных), потому что реализация своего такого - сложновата, да и специфична; а вот по обычным - вопрос остается открытым.